# How to use POST command in Alamofire to send this JSON object?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm fetching two fields from text boxes in my iOS app and I want to send the following JSON object back to the server.(Using AlamoFire) When the user enters the username and password , this data should be sent as JSON object back to the server.
How should I write my POST method for sending this particular JSON object?
My JSON is as follows:

```
   { "settings": 
       {
          "username": "myUserName",
          "password": "myPassword123"
       }
   }
```

This is my class in Swift 3,

```
class logIN {

    let username: String! = nil
    let password: String! = nil

init(ssid: String, password: String) {

    let parameters: [String: String] = [
            "username": ssid as String,
            "password": password as String
        ]

    var statusCode: Int = 0
    Alamofire.request("URL_HERE", parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON { response in
            statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)! 
            print(String(statusCode))

        }
    }
}
```

This is my IBAction for the Done button , which when clicked will send the POST request.

```
@IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let logInInstance = logIN(ssid : self.username.text!, password : self.password.text!)

}
```

Comment: `Alamofire.request("URL_HERE", parameters: ["settings":parameters])`

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 LOL, that needs an upvote :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let loginParam: [String: String] = [
                "username": ssid as String,
                "password": password as String
            ]

    var parameters = [String:Any]()
    parameters["setting"] = loginParam

    var statusCode: Int = 0
    Alamofire.request("URL_HERE", parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON { response in
            statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)! 
            print(String(statusCode))

        }
    }
```